# Ambiguous reference error in OpenApi-generated c# code

Tags: c#, openapi-generator

I'm using OpenAPI Generator to generate client libraries for my c# API. I am having issues generating a c# client, because one of my models is called Environment. The generated service code to manipulate this model causes the build of the project to fail because it is an ambiguous reference between it's own model and .Net's System.Environment.

The exact error I'm seeing is 
`Api/EnvironmentApi.cs(87,42): error CS0104: 'Environment' is an ambiguous reference between 'MyProject.Model.Environment' and 'System.Environment'`

Is there some way to tell openapi-generator to fully-qualify the class names in the generated code so that it won't clash? i.e. so it generates something like

`DoSomething<MyProject.Model.Environment>(...)` instead of `DoSomething<Environment>(...)`

Comment: you can create  alias for one of the dll

Answer (score 1):

*In a nutshell*: `--model-name-prefix` can save your build.

---

*In more details:*

Generating fully-qualified class names does not seems possible (as [this feature request](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/16123) is still open), but there is a workaround though, with the option `--model-name-prefix` that was added in OpenApi-Generator [a couple years ago](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/commit/a6f3914a92c0e455bf48a442cb210637856b5f4e).

To leverage it, add on you command line something like `--model-name-prefix SomePrefix`.

The impact is that instead of generating the model class `Environment` it will generate the class `SomePrefixEnvironment`.

So, sure, you may dislike having this prefix added everywhere, but at least you won't have build conflict anymore

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since the request was opened for swagger: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/2630

Bear in mind that I'm referring swagger as it is the project that was forked to make openapi generator. 
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/migration-from-swagger-codegen.md#new-fully-qualified-name-for-the-classes

> OpenAPI Generator is a fork of swagger-codegen between version `2.3.1` and `2.4.0`

So the answer is most probably no.